# Is it legal for an unlicensed person to transmit as long as they are under the direct supervision of a licensed amateur?

Tags: united-states, legal

Based on another question here, I think it is legal, but I would like it directly from the people who know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Here's what I found [searching for *control operator*](https://ham.stackexchange.com/search?q=Control+operator), which is what the licensed amateur supervising is known as.  This may or may not be a [duplicate question](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/how-strictly-should-the-close-as-duplicate-rule-be-enforced).

Comment: @Mike if you think it would improve the answer, the definition of "control operator" can certainly be edited in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, according to FCC part 97.115...as long as the licenced control operator is present and supervising. There is at least one exception though - the third-party operator cannot have previously had a license revoked.

Here is section 115:

> § 97.115 Third party communications.
>
> (a) An amateur station may transmit  messages for a third party to:
>
> (1) Any station within the jurisdiction of the United States.
>
> (2) Any station within the jurisdiction of any foreign government when
>   transmitting emergency or disaster relief communications and any
>   station within the jurisdiction of any foreign government whose
>   administration has made arrangements with the United States to allow
>   amateur stations to be used for transmitting international
>   communications on behalf of third parties.
>
> No station shall transmit messages for a third party to any station
>   within the jurisdiction of any foreign government whose administration
>   has not made such an arrangement. This prohibition does not apply to a
>   message for any third party who is eligible to be a control operator
>   of the station.
>
> (b) The third party may participate in stating the message where:
>
> (1) The control operator is present at the control point and is
>   continuously  monitoring and supervising the third party’s
>   participation; and
>
> (2) The third party is not a prior amateur service licensee whose
>   license  was revoked or not renewed after hearing and re-licensing has
>   not taken  place; suspended for less than the balance of the license
>   term and the suspension is still in effect; suspended for the balance
>   of the license term and re-licensing has not taken place; or
>   surrendered for cancellation following notice of revocation,
>   suspension or monetary forfeiture proceedings. The third  party may
>   not be the subject of a cease and desist order which relates to
>   amateur service operation and which is still in effect.
>
> (c) No station may transmit third party communications while being
>   automatically controlled except a station transmitting a RTTY or data
>   emission.
>
> (d) At the end of an exchange of international third party
>   communications, the station must also transmit in the station
>   identification procedure the call sign of the station with which a
>   third party message was exchanged.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking at section b2. It basically says that a person cannot be a third party if their license was not revoked. Does this include an individual who has had a license but allowed it to expire? Can a person like that be a third party who is under supervision?

Comment: They way I read it, a former licensee with an expired ticket is ok for third party - the exclusion is based on revocation/suspension without reinstatement.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you.

Comment: Also, third party traffic rules apply, which means that you can't make contacts with countries with which we do not have a third party agreement.  (I think it's a very short list.)

Comment: Re: "cannot have previously had a license revoked" --  this answer mis-reads these admittedly baroque words. Ultimately, what the quoted text is trying to say is that if the third party was a licensed amateur **and takes part in the conversation**, they must have a currently valid license. The rest of it is listing conditions that make the license invalid. In particular, note in (b)(2) "revoked ... and re-licensing has not taken place". The rest of (b)(2) is variations on that theme.

Comment: @PeteNU9W that's not how I read it. To me, "not renewed after hearing" means those people who get cited and let their licenses expire rather than contesting the charges.  I don't think that paragraph applies to people who let their licenses expire in the ordinary way.  But I'm no lawyer.  Do you have any documentation that supports your interpretation?

Comment: The third party does not need a currently valid license.  The third party, however, must not have a license that was revoked due to previous misbehavior that directly caused it to be revoked.  I.e. third party traffic is not a free ride for past violators.  This has nothing to do with expired licenses, but REVOKED licenses.  You can still renew an expired license.  You can't renew a revoked license without another hearing.

Comment: @rclocher3 -- the point is that this prohibition prevents using the third-party rule as a way of operating despite being prohibited from having a license because of a suspension or revocation. Once that suspension or revocation has been lifted, i.e., by getting a license, the prohibition no longer applies. That's much narrower than "cannot have previously had a license revoked", which implies a lifetime ban.